# PHP - cookie is not set when expire date is too far in the future

Tags: php, cookies, methods, setcookie

**FOUND THE ISSUE, see below at the end**

I have a php page in wich I save a cookie :

```
include "scripts/mytoolkit.php";

...
if ($val != "") saveCookie('mycookie', $val, 100*365, "www.domain.com");  // tested, $val is not empty and is a string. Want to keep the cookie for 100 years :-))
...
```

with mytoolkit.php

```
function saveCookie($name, $value, $days, $domain)
{
$expires = 0;

    // tested, $name and $value are correct and filled

    if (isset($days)) 
           $expires = time()+$days*24*60*60;   // tested, the method enters there

    setcookie ($name, $value, $expires, "/", $domain);
}

function readCookie($name)
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$name])) return $_COOKIE[$name];
    return null;
}
```

Later, after having reloaded the page, I check the cookie and print it :

```
...
$val = readCookie('mycookie');
print ($val);
...
```

The problem is that $val is empty, and of course the cookie is not set.

BUT...

if I just replace the call :

```
saveCookie('mycookie', $val, 100*365, "www.domain.com");
```

by the following :

```
setcookie ('mycookie', $val, time()+100*365, "/", "www.domain.com");
```

or by keeping

```
 saveCookie('mycookie', $val, 100*365, "www.domain.com");
```

but removing `*24*60*60;` from the `saveCookie` method

Then everything works fine and $val is filled with the cookie value, and the cookie is well set.

What is going wrong with the use of the method to set the cookie ?

**ISSUE**

The issue was the fact I wanted to keep the cookie 100 years. If I put a more limited delay, like 10 years, it works fine.

The question is : why can I use 100 years in javascript when I set a cookie, and why can't I do the same using PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.php.net/set_cookie:

> The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number
>   of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set
>   this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you
>   want it to expire. Or you might use mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 will
>   set the cookie to expire in 30 days. If set to 0, or omitted, the
>   cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser
>   closes).

The problem maybe is because you're trying to set an expire timestamp that exceed the unix timestamp limit **AND** your php is a 32 bits version. The limit of the unix timestamp on system that uses a 32 bits int is January 19, 2038.

From http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php:

> **What happens on January 19, 2038?**
>
> On this date the Unix Time Stamp will cease to work due to a 32-bit
>   overflow. Before this moment millions of applications will need to
>   either adopt a new convention for time stamps or be migrated to 64-bit
>   systems which will buy the time stamp a "bit" more time.